# Visual Studio release build runs very slow inside Visual Studio vs. outside

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

If I run my console application with release build in Visual studio it takes 50 seconds to execute, but when I run the same EXE from a console outside VS it takes only 3.5 seconds to complete, how so and how can I get it to run faster in VS?

The only build flag I use is "Optimize Code", my workstation has a i7 processor, the program does no disk I/O, database access, nor any network action - all is just pure processing work in-memory.

There are a lot of exceptions thrown says the Debug Output in Visual studio from DLL's that are part of other packages than mine, but the program seems to run fine so I guess these are caught and handled.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

Comment: Do you have the debugger attached in VS?  Check out [Just my code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346.aspx)

Comment: Try running in VS with Ctrl+F5 (no debugger attached)

Comment: Its probably the writing of the exceptions to the output screen. Printing large amounts of lines to your output window can really slow things down (same as a normal console really). As the others mentioned, try it without the debugger.